# Error explode in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

my code is like this.

```
$idwisa = "288";
$stemp = DB::table('t_hasil_temp')
    ->select('hasil')
    ->where('id', $idwisa)
    ->get();
```

when `print_r($stemp);` I get `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [hasil] => 20,24,22,26 ) )` and `hasil` is a string

I want convert `hasil` to array and I try like this. And the problem is in this `explode`.

```
$temp = explode(",",$stemp->hasil); // error Trying to get property of non-object
```

or

```
$temp = explode(",",$stemp); // error explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

because after that I will use `$temp` like this.

```
$temps = Objek::whereIn('id',$temp)->get();
```

Any solution? thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$temp = explode(",",$stemp[0]->hasil); 
print_r($temp);
```

Because your array is multidimensional array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use of `->get()` and `->first()`

change here to get single object

```
$stemp = DB::table('t_hasil_temp')
   ->select('hasil')
   ->where('id', $idwisa)
   ->first();
```

`->get()` gives array of object although you have one object but you need to add `0th` value of array. here `$stemp[0]`

Answer (score 0):

`->get()` returns an array of results, it seems that you want to use `->first()` which returns only the first found result.

```
$stemp = DB::table('t_hasil_temp')
    ->select('hasil')
    ->where('id', $idwisa)
    ->first();
```

Also, if you have a `HasilTemp` Model, you might also use:

```
$stemp = HasilTemp::find($idwisa);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the concept, when you use

`->get();`

It returns:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [hasil] => 20,24,22,26 ) ) which is a stdClass Object
```

and you can access its element like:

```
$stemp[0]->hasil;
```